# Como puedo Ordenar esta tabla mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente tabla donde la Ordeno por `prioridad` y `id_agenda`, el orden debe ser de la siguiente manera Prioridad ASC y `id_agenda` DESC (En caso un dato no tiene prioridad asi que este debe ir debajo de los que si tiene prioridad).

sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ACT_Agenda` (
  `id_agenda` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `prioridad` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `actividad` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_agenda`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=83 ;

INSERT INTO `ACT_Agenda` (`id_agenda`, `prioridad`, `actividad`) VALUES
(51, 1, 'act1'),
(60, 2, 'act2'),
(62, 3, 'act3'),
(70, NULL, 'act4'),
(71, NULL, 'act5'),
```

Aqui mi Codigo donde ordeno.

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM ACT_Agenda as a
       ORDER BY prioridad DESC, id_agenda DESC ";
```

Mi resultado. [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6b0398/1)

```
---------------------------
|id |prioridad|  actividad|
----|---------|-----------|
|62 |   3     |act1       | <--Debería ordenar por la primera prioridad
|60 |   2     |act2       |
|51 |   1     |act3       |
|71 |         |act5       | <--Ultimo valor ingresado
|70 |         |act4       |
|---|---------|-----------|
```

Pero si ordeno por prioridad ASC se desordena la tabla dejando la ultima `id` primero. Me gustaria tener un resultado asi .

```
---------------------------
|id |prioridad|  actividad|
----|---------|-----------|
|51 |   1     |act1       | <--Ordena por primera prioridad
|60 |   2     |act2       |
|62 |   3     |act3       |
|71 |         |act5       | <--Ultimo valor ingresado
|70 |         |act4       |
|---|---------|-----------|
```

Comment: Deberías aclarar un poco la pregunta. Por ejemplo: ¿Qué es `id_agenda`? (aparece en la consulta pero no en la tabla) O en la explicación menciones que ordenas por prioridad ASC, pero luego en la consulta la ordenas DESC, ¿cuál es la que haces? ¿y qué resultados obtienes?

Comment: la `id_agenda` es un numero autoincrementable

Comment: Podes agregar como es que sale tu resultado, y los datos de origen? ese orden no suena logico, o mas bien, suena logico como esta ordenando...

Comment: @gbianchi ok agregare el resultado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Efectivamente en MySQL, los NULL son considerados menor que cualquier otro valor no NULL, excepto si agregas el carácter `-`antes de el nombre de la columna en el Order By y el ASC se cambia a DESC o viceversa.
Mira el siguiente link: [Comparison of different SQL implementations](http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/#select-order_by)

SqlFiddle: [sqlfiddle-ejemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6b0398/11/0)

La consulta debiera quedar asi:

```
SELECT * FROM ACT_Agenda as a
       ORDER BY -prioridad DESC, id_agenda DESC
```

Y tendrás el resultado esperado.

Answer (score 4):

Al ordenar por el campo `prioridad` en orden `ASC` se colocan primero los que están en null. Una variante para lograrlo es hacer una unión de dos consultas, primero con los que no están en null y colocando los otros detrás.

```
(SELECT * FROM ACT_Agenda 
where prioridad is not null ORDER BY prioridad ASC, id_agenda DESC )
union
(select * from ACT_Agenda where prioridad is null order by id_agenda DESC LIMIT 1000)
```

Nota que es importante los paréntesis en la segunda parte de la consulta porque sino aplica el último `order by` al resultado de la unión volviendo a la situación original.

Comment: me muestra este error `#1221 - Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY`

Comment: Le agregue `()` al primer select pero me ordena por la id_agenda `desc` solamente.

Comment: Agrege un SQL Fiddle

Comment: Me ordena bien  las `id_prioridad`, pero la `id_agenda` debería ordenar por la ultima `id_agenda`. Gracias de todos modos

Comment: Edité la consulta, ya da el resultado esperado solo por incluir LIMIT, según la documentación oficial "An ORDER BY with and without LIMIT may return rows in different orders, as discussed in Section 8.2.1.17, “LIMIT Query Optimization”." No obstante con ello la consulta queda más complicada de usar, la respuesta de [MBahamondes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/208215/24400) es más simple y debes usarla en el escenario de la pregunta original. También quedó arreglado el problema original que la consulta daba error.